# Delphi won't parse external DTD file

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing, schema, delphi-xe

I have an XML like this (simplified version for easy understanding):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PubmedArticleSet>
<PubmedArticle>

    <MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="In-Process">
    </MedlineCitation>

    <PubmedData>
    </PubmedData>

</PubmedArticle>
</PubmedArticleSet>
```

I want to create an XML parser starting from its DTD, using Delphi's "XML data binding" wizard.
The problem is that the description of 'MedlineCitation' is in an external DTD:

```
<!ENTITY % Medline PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD Medline, 01 Jan 2015//EN"  "nlmmedlinecitationset_150101.dtd">
%Medline;
```

The second DTD file is in the same folder as the main DTD.
The wizard will see/parse 'MedlineCitation' as a simple string. Obviously, when I run the program and try to read the 'MedlineCitation' it crashes with the message "Element MedlineCitation does not contain a single text node".

---

DTD 1 (main)
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/corehtml/query/DTD/pubmed_150101.dtd

DTD 2 ('MedlineCitation')
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/corehtml/query/DTD/nlmmedlinecitationset_150101.dtd

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the 'big hammer' approach. I simply took the DTD 2 text and paste it in DTD 1 (with minor modifications).

This totally works but it a bit 'brute force'. If you have a better solution please post and I will accept your answer.